# Non-Apple hosted DLC In-App-Purchase Submission process for iTune Connect

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I was reading this page [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW3)

Will be nice if anyone can answer my question.
From my best knowledge, I can sell Non-Consumable DLC In-App-Purchase item in Apple.
And I can choose either the Non-Consumable item to be apple-hosted or not.
My question here is, how does the review process will work?

I know that if is Apple-hosted, then I would upload the DLC to Apple.
But in the case which is not, do (and how) Apple will review my DLC?  Or I will just describe what the DLC is and Apple will approve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit each In-App-Purchase for review. They will get reviewed individually. In iTunes Connect you have to provide at least one screenshot "showing" your In-App-Purchase. Depending on your content the review team will need a demo account or ask for more information.